# Fit width as in display:inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists, text-align

I would like to do responsive centered list of boxes.
So I used `text-align:center`, but the last line is centered too:
http://jsfiddle.net/NWmpL/1/

I was trying to use additional wrapper which closely surrounds `<li>`, 
but only way which I know to "closely surround" content is using `display:inline` 
http://jsfiddle.net/NWmpL/2/
but here `text-align:left` dont working

 And `width:200px` should be flexible (because in my case it is browser width)

Is there any other way to "closely surround" content? Or is there any other solution ?

Thanks in advance.

More clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/NWmpL/6/

I want change this
[image]
 to this [image]

Comment: Does the ordering of the boxes matter? (If not, you could look at css3 columns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts)

Comment: your second fiddle is not valid, you cannot have a div as a child of the ul.

Comment: Pete I know, I want to have solution without using js, not wc3 correction :)

Comment: @lenrok7 - Don't dismiss Pete's comment. You should listen when people make comments on incorrect; very often with questions like this it is the invalid markup that causes the layout issue. In this case, using the correct display property fixes things (see my answer), but the first thing you should always do when you have a layout issue is correct any HTML validation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `display:inline-block` for layout, not `display:inline`.

`display:inline` is only intended for text content; if you have any block content inside the element and you want inline behaviour, you should always use `inline-block` instead.

So I went to your fiddle and changed the `inline` to `inline-block`.

Guess what.... that fixed the problem; it now looks the way you wanted.

See http://jsfiddle.net/NWmpL/8/

You could also consider using `float:left` to achieve this kind of layout, but since we've got a working answer with `inline-block`, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I really consider all this solutions.. the problem is not to aling all to left but, align each individual <li> to left line where first started (on the picture), and keep all together centered, not forgetting about their flexibility.
Anyway, thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
float:left;
```

to

```
.center li { }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWmpL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.center {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:250px; }

ul.center li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width:75px; height:75px;    
    margin: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #CCC; }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4t6ha/2/

Try this different approach:

CSS:

```
.holder
{
width:300px;
border:1px dotted #000;
float:left;
padding:5px 5px;
}

ul
{
list-style:none;
}

li
{
display:inline-block;
height:30px;
width:30px;
background:#dedede;
margin:2px;
float:left;
padding:10px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```